# I am the protector everytime

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge

I am the protector during a fright. 
But you are not going to find me in any sight.

I am the protector during a fight. 
But you will find me a little heavier than light.

I am the protector during a flight. 
But you will not find me flying like a kite.

Your body will beat more as soon as you face me. 
Too much of my presence will kill you, and you will later see.

Can you guess who am I?

I will provide hints as time goes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are

> Adrenaline because it more or less fits all the clues.

Some rough areas (as requested by DrD)

I am the protector during a fright.
But you are not going to find me in any sight.

> During fear andrenaline gives you energy so you can either fend of or flee the threat. It is invisible to the naked eye.

I am the protector during a fight.
But you will find me a little heavier than light.

> Adrenaline enhances ones energies and reflexes fight are useful in a fight to hit and not get hit It makes one's heart beat more heavily so I guess its presence will be percieved as 'heavy.'

I am the protector during a flight.
But you will not find me flying like a kite

> It helps gives you more energy to run faster from danger thus helping you get away and saving you from harm. Adrenaline being just a chemical cannot fly kites.

Your body will beat more as soon as you face me.

> Adrenalin causes your heart to beat more when it increases in quantity in the blood stream.

Too much of my presence will kill you, and you will later see

> In excess, adrenaline will cause you a heart attack, it also causes your pupils to dilate, I guess enhancing vision.

Comment: Hi @Smartest1here , I am a little confused. Can you explain how it fits "heavier than light or not flying like a kite" clues? Thanks

Comment: @Smartest1here Guess I am late, hey you are right. If you can give the explanation for each stanza it will be better, and I will give the checkmark too. (The meaning should be correct).